Is it possible to split a hex string like this using just regex?
Given the following input string (with no whitespaces in it):
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10111213...

Is it possible to write a substitution regex that would produce the following output?
\t0x00, 0x01, 0x02, ... 0x0F\n
\t0x10, 0x11, 0x12, ...

Basically, split the hex string into groups of 16 bytes, comma separate individual 16 bytes, add 0x prefix to each, and insert tab and newline characters on 16-byte boundary.
I can match two hex characters with [[:xdigit:]]{2}, which allows me to substitute using 0x$1,  to get individual bytes formatted the way I want, but I can't think of a way of doing the newline and tab insertion after each 16 bytes.
I guess that "Not possible using regex" will be an acceptable answer to the question (if backed with a link to docs that explain why) — what won't be accepted are suggestions to use programming languages to format the string because I already know how to do that.

What tool/language are you using for this task?

it is trivial but tedious if input contains an exact multiple of 32 hex characters, and the RE flavour allows 16 backreferences

also trivial if two consecutive substitutions are allowed

We need to know which tool you use, because regexes alone don't replace things. They match things.

To do the nested substitutions, you need a language that allows using a function as the replacement for a regexp. The main regexp would match up to 16 pairs. The replacement function then matches each pair and adds 0x and space around each of them.

My question was whether it is possible in a single step with just search and replace regex such as on regex101.com.

If your string always has the same pattern--varying only in length--you only need its length to construct the resultant string; there is no point to parsing the given string.

If you are using a flavour of PCRE that supports conditional substitution, you could do this generically by matching:
(..)(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?(..)?

i.e. a pair of characters followed by 15 optional pairs of characters, and then replacing it with
\t0x$1${2:+, 0x$2:}${3:+, 0x$3:}${4:+, 0x$4:}${5:+, 0x$5:}${6:+, 0x$6:}${7:+, 0x$7:}${8:+, 0x$8:}${9:+, 0x$9:}${10:+, 0x$10:}${11:+, 0x$11:}${12:+, 0x$12:}${13:+, 0x$13:}${14:+, 0x$14:}${15:+, 0x$15:}${16:+, 0x$16:}\n

The conditional substitutions add , 0x in front of any of the optional groups that match.
For this input:
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122

The output will be:
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22

Demo on regex101
Note that if you know you always have a multiple of 32 digits, you can simplify the regex to:
(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)

and the substitution to:
\t0x$1, 0x$2, 0x$3, 0x$4, 0x$5, 0x$6, 0x$7, 0x$8, 0x$9, 0x$10, 0x$11, 0x$12, 0x$13, 0x$14, 0x$15, 0x$16\n

Demo on regex101
Note I've assumed you're trying to replace an entire string of hex digits; if that is not the case you need to replace .. (match any pair of characters) with [0-9a-f]{2} (and add the i flag and possibly word breaks \b at each end of the regex) to only match the hex digits within the string.
Demo on regex101

Data is a hex dump so it is always multiple of 2 digits (i.e. a byte), and not always multiple of 16 bytes. If that can help optimize the expression further that would be great, if not I am accepting your answer as-is.

Instead of (..) you should put ([[:xdigit:]]{2}), and in substitute you should add   (space) after comma.

@IgorLevicki if there are only hex digits, matching with . is more efficient than matching with a character class (as the current character only has to be checked for existence, not whether it is one of a set of characters or not). If there isn't always a multiple of 16 bytes then I don't think you can get more efficient than what I wrote in the answer. I did notice I left the space out of the substitution but figured it was easy enough to add in.

Thanks for clarification. For the sake of completeness I can edit your answer to add spaces if you don't want to do it.

@IgorLevicki I see you made the edit while I was sleeping :) I've approved it.
